# Access 2007 - Get VB user login and record for last modified form

Tags: database, ms-access

I created one of microsoft access 2007 database. which is created two forms. 1.employee form. 
table name "tbl employee": ID,IC NO, Name, Office Branch.
2.login form. : 
table name "tble User" : UID,Username,Password,Enable,Fullname.

As usual when i login the username(using combobox) and password(using textbox) the login form is working properly as I'm using VB as shown below:-

```
Private Sub cbo_User_AfterUpdate()
 Me.txt_Password = Empty
    Me.txt_Password.Enabled = True
    Me.txt_Password.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_OK_Click()
'test the stored password is = to the manually entered password
    If Me.cbo_User.Column(2) = Me.txt_Password Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "fm_employee", acNormal
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Login"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "fm_switchboard"
    Else 'wrong match
        MsgBox "Wrong password entered." & _
            vbCrLf & "Please re-enter password.", _
            vbExclamation, "Invalid Password"
        Me.txt_Password.SetFocus 'places the cursor in password control
    End If
    'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown

    intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
    If intLogonAttempts > 3 Then
      MsgBox "You do not have access to this database.Please contact admin.", _
               vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, I need help How to get the fullname or Username from login form and record into the field when after User Client MODIFIED and SAVE every single record from employee form.

Note: login user is more than 1

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you could indent the code in your question.  Indent 4 spaces deep, and formatting will be preserved.

Comment: Is this coded in VBA in Access? If so, the line `Me.txt_Password = Empty` can't be correct, as `Empty` should be `Null`. I also question what you're doing here -- it's fake security and doesn't really do anything at all to protect your data. If you're using it to control program flow, you might be better off using the Windows logon name, as then you'd no longer need to worry about passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to record who makes changes to a record based on who is logged in to the database. In that case, hide rather than close frmLogin. You can do this with Me.Visible=false. You can then create an event procedure for the BeforeUpdate event of the form fm_employee. In that event procedure, set the field for who modified the record to equal Forms!frmLogin!cbo_User.

Comment: Pse correct me if i'm wrong, before i put the code, I created one more field in my table employee which is last modified. from the field properties in BeforeUpdate event is shown like this:-



first line: Private Sub Last_Modified_BeforeUpdate (Cancel As Integer)

second line:Forms!frm_Login!cbo_User >>> (this code become red color)

third line: End Sub


Btw i'm really thankful with your inputs.

Comment: Unless you're allowing the user to edit the Last_Modified field, an event on that field will never fire. You want to create Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate and put the following in the function:
Last_Modified.Value=Now()
Last_Modified_By.Value=Forms!frmLogin!cbo_User

Does that help?